# Numerical Integration with constants

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, matlab, sagemath, numerical-calculus

I am having trouble trying to integrate the following integral numerically because of the constant z $$\int_{-5}^5(x^2+z^2)^{-1}(x^2+25+z^2)^{-0.5}dx$$ Is there any way to evaluate this integral on Sage?

Comment: Do you have some table of values of $z$ where you want to evaluate it?

Comment: I am using the integral to obtain a function of z so that I can determine which value of z will satisfy my problem. So I am not sure what z values I want. I am trying to set this integral equal to approximately 113

Comment: OK, then you can use an iterative method to solve for $z$, for example Matlab's fsolve (or something similar in numpy) or a hand-coded secant method.

Comment: Can't you compute the integral exactly, as a function of $z$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson is right, by asking a CAS with some particular values of $z$, it looks like this can be done analytically using the substitution $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+25+z^2}}$.

Comment: How could I do this on a CAS? Is there a way to get the system to do it or would I do the substitution by hand?

Comment: In Wolfram Alpha you can try it for a few fixed values of $z$ and you'll figure out the general formula easily enough. I'm not sure whether Mathematica can do the symbolic version. Of course doing the substitution by hand is not really that difficult, you will find that you get an arctan-type integral out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ian commented, using the substitution $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+25+z^2}}$, you should end with
$$I=\int(x^2+z^2)^{-1}(x^2+25+z^2)^{-\frac12}\,dx=\int \frac{du}{25 u^2+z^2}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 u}{z}\right)}{5 z}$$

Back to $x$
$$I=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 x}{z \sqrt{x^2+z^2+25}}\right)}{5 z}$$ and
$$J(a)=\int_{-a}^{+a}(x^2+z^2)^{-1}(x^2+25+z^2)^{-\frac12}\,dx=\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 a}{z \sqrt{a^2+z^2+25}}\right)}{5 z}$$ What is seems is that you search for $z$ such that
$$k=J(5)=\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{25}{z \sqrt{z^2+50}}\right)}{5 z}$$ where $k$ is known.

This is a transcendental equation and you will need some numerical method (Newton would be the simplest to use). The problem is that you need a starting guess $z_0$.

Using a series expansion built at $z=0$, you could get
$$k=\frac{\pi }{5 z}-\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{25}+\frac{z^2}{375 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(z^4\right)$$ and using series reversion
$$z=\frac{\pi }{5 k}-\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \pi }{125 k^2}+\frac{8 \pi }{3125
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$
Using this value for $z_0$, let us try for $k=0.567$. The iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z_n \\
 0 & 0.9311508109 \\
 1 & 0.9259359776 \\
 2 & 0.9259652138 \\
 3 & 0.9259652147
\end{array}
\right)$$